# What is the morning blessing Roka Haaretz - רוֹקַע הָאָרֶץ עַל הַמָּיִם - all about?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, creation

One of the daily morning blessings is רוֹקַע הָאָרֶץ עַל הַמָּיִם - *He solidifies the ground above the water.*

We're thanking Hashem for the solid ground; the inhabited world isn't all marshy or liquid which would make life really difficult.

My question is: If Hashem had made the *ground under our feet* less than solid, He would have made our bodies appropriate for the marsh/liquid. Same as ducks and penguins survive just fine as created.

So why are we thanking Hashem for Solid Ground?

Comment: How's this different from the other blessings? If we couldn't see we'd have echolocation. If we couldn't walk standing we'd walk on all fours.

Answer (score 2):

All the brachos are like this. Anyways, who said who would have given us the necessary tools to live with it. Maybe we would have been forced to accept this challenge of walking through marshy ground, just like He gave us other challenges, e.g. like the need to constantly eat, and not being self-sustained.